# Как избежать удаления функции _start при межмодульной оптимизации?

Tags: c, оптимизация, gcc

При следующем значении `CFLAGS`:

```
-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -O3 -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
```

моя точка входа `__start` (обратите внимание на `-nostartfiles`) успешно компилируется и помещается в исполняемый файл.

Однако при добавлении флага `-flto` и сама точка входа, и все вызываемые только ей функции выкидываются оптимизатором. Более того, дальнейшая компоновка производится без ошибок и предупреждений, но с некорректной (случайной) точкой входа.

**Вопрос:** как предотвратить удаление функции `__start`? Также интересно узнать, почему компоновщик во время оптимизации «забывает» о наличие зависимости от *моей* точки входа при отсутствии встроенной.

Версия GCC: *gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2*.

**Исходный код** (исправлено с учётом замечания об особенностях Windows ABI *[в оригинале это был [комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556307/prevent-start-entry-point-from-being-optimized-out#comment66424332_39556307), но здесь я добавил его в ответ — прим. пер.]*):

```
#include <windows.h>

void _start()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hello world."), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Ассемблерный код, выдаваемый компоновщиком (`-S`):

1. Вариант без `-flto`:

   ```
   Disassembly of section .text:

   00401000 <__start>:
     401000:       83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
     401003:       c7 44 24 0c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xc(%esp)
     40100a:       00
     40100b:       c7 44 24 08 00 20 40    movl   $0x402000,0x8(%esp)
     401012:       00
     401013:       c7 44 24 04 0d 20 40    movl   $0x40200d,0x4(%esp)
     40101a:       00
     40101b:       c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
     401022:       ff 15 54 40 40 00       call   *0x404054
     401028:       83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
     40102b:       c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
     401032:       ff 15 4c 40 40 00       call   *0x40404c
     401038:       90                      nop
     401039:       90                      nop
     40103a:       90                      nop
     40103b:       90                      nop
     40103c:       90                      nop
     40103d:       90                      nop
     40103e:       90                      nop
     40103f:       90                      nop

   00401040 <__CTOR_LIST__>:
     401040:       ff                      (bad)
     401041:       ff                      (bad)
     401042:       ff                      (bad)
     401043:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     401045:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
           ...

   00401048 <__DTOR_LIST__>:
     401048:       ff                      (bad)
     401049:       ff                      (bad)
     40104a:       ff                      (bad)
     40104b:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     40104d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   ```
2. Вариант с `-flto` (обратите внимание на отсутствие `_start`, но наличие переходников для API-функций):

   ```
   Disassembly of section .text:

   00401000 <_ExitProcess@4>:
     401000:       ff 25 4c 30 40 00       jmp    *0x40304c
     401006:       90                      nop
     401007:       90                      nop

   00401008 <_MessageBoxA@16>:
     401008:       ff 25 54 30 40 00       jmp    *0x403054
     40100e:       90                      nop
     40100f:       90                      nop

   00401010 <__CTOR_LIST__>:
     401010:       ff                      (bad)
     401011:       ff                      (bad)
     401012:       ff                      (bad)
     401013:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     401015:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
           ...

   00401018 <__DTOR_LIST__>:
     401018:       ff                      (bad)
     401019:       ff                      (bad)
     40101a:       ff                      (bad)
     40101b:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     40101d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   ```

---

*Данный вопрос является переводом «[Prevent __start entry point from being optimized out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39556307/2553424)».*

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556307/prevent-start-entry-point-from-being-optimized-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо удостовериться, что данный символ воспринимается как точка входа и не выбрасывается при оптимизации на уровне компоновщика.

Чтобы указать точку входа, необходимо передать компоновщику следующий ключ:

```
-Wl,-e__start
```

либо написать spec-файл с объявлением данного символа. Однако способ с ключом проще.

*И ещё. При использовании Windows ABI компилятор неявно добавляет дополнительное подчёркивание перед именем Си-функций. Как результат, `void __start()` превращается в `___start`, и компоновщик его не видит.*

---

*Данный ответ является переводом [ответа участника Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39557199/2553424) и [комментария участника fuz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556307/prevent-start-entry-point-from-being-optimized-out#comment66424332_39556307).*