# Обработка ответа Stormpath Id Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Я учусь работать с Stormpath. Нужно сделать авторизацию через Id Site. Я создал Action'ны запроса и ответа и успешно получил аккаунт. Но что делать дальше?

```
public async Task<RedirectResult> Callback(string jwtResponse)
{
    var client = Request.GetStormpathClient();
    var app = await client.GetApplicationAsync(appUrl);
    var requestDescriptor = HttpRequests.NewRequestDescriptor()
    .WithMethod("GET")
    .WithUri("http://localhost:50084/Auth/Callback?jwtResponse=" + jwtResponse)
    .Build();
    var idSiteListener = app.NewIdSiteAsyncCallbackHandler(requestDescriptor);
    var accountResult = await idSiteListener.GetAccountResultAsync();
    var account = accountResult.GetAccountAsync().Result; //Аккаунт
    //Что нужно сделать что бы сказать приложению что пользователь авторизировался
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

Comment: Ответ на английской копии моего вопроса
[stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132859/how-to-handle-stormpath-id-site-jwt-response)

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, ещё и ответ (пусть он и не ваш). И ещё, переводы можно оформлять следующим образом: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612588/208074